# MVC: Refresh form after Ajax post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an two actions named AddContact, one decorated with [HttpGet] and what with [HttpPost].  I do an Ajax post and the contact is added, but the form still has the data in it.  How do I make the form clear after post?

I am fairly new to MVC and up to this point, I've always done a redirect after a post because I read that you should always do that.  This is the first time I actually want to remain on the same page.  I mean, I could rename the AddContact method to something different for GET and POST and redirect to the get action after post, but that's kind of clunky to me.  Is there a good way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The entire purpose of AJAX is to avoid redirecting when its not necessary.. Just don't redirect, there's no standard that says you have to. Nice handle BTW :P

Comment: Thanks lol.  My my middle name is actually Sheldon and my last name is Cooper, and I created this account before I even became aware of BBT.

Comment: Redirect or no redirect, after post, the form area is refreshed, but the form data is not cleared.  How do I get the form data to clear so it's a new form?

Comment: Follow the standard PRG pattern. Do a standard submit and redirect back to the GET method (no need to rename anything)

Comment: You are right, I forgot to put the return in from of the call to RedirectToAction().  Put it as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a javascript function to reset the form on a AJAX success.  So with that in mind you could build an array with all of your forms inputs something like this

```
var inputarray = ["#one","#two","#three"];
```

Then simply call a function on the Ajax Success so this is an example of the AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: form,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(ajaxresult) {
            if (ajaxresult === 0) {
                formClear();
            }
        }
    });
```

Then have a javascript function called formClear and have something like this

```
for (var i=0; i < inputarray.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(inputarray[i]).value = "";
}
```

Make sure your controller returns a JsonResult of 0 for success or 1 for error so something like this

```
return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Here is a simple jsfiddle example (this has no ajax call but you get my drift)
http://jsfiddle.net/ed1hgk4g/

Comment: Obviously I would use an external JS file and not inline script tag